# IIS7 Export Redirect Settings

Tags: iis-7, http, redirect

I'm looking to export about 50 folders in IIS7 that use HTTP Redirect to redirect visitors. A while back I imported about 100 others from IIS6 and I'm able to now find those in the applicationHost.config file.

The 50 I've created since in IIS7 are not in that applicationHost.config file. Is there a way to easily import those to a new IIS7 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS7 uses a concept of distributed configuration.  This means that some changes are distributed to the site's web.config files.  That's probably what happened here.  If you check your site's web.config file, you should find the HTTP Redirects.

You can migrate them simply by copy and pasting them to either the new server's web.config file, or you can manually copy them to apphost in a location tag, like your current IIS7's first 50 folders.